# R: calculate the unique count of observations that meet conditions across two different columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example dataset that contains the details of a survey. The id is repeated for number of members in the famiy. I aim to get the total count of households, identify the sum of households with 3 to 5 family members, and find out the count of households with fewer than 3 or more than 5 family members.
I have tried the following codes which did not work.

```
 library(dplyr)
 #sample df
 df <- data.frame(
      Year = rep(2022:2023, times = c(20,25)),
      ID = rep(1:17, times = c(10, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
      Name = paste("name", 1:45), 
      Age = 21:65, 
      Coverage = rep("Yes", 45) 
    )
    # adding number of family size to each observation  
    df<- df %>% mutate(hh_count  = stringr::str_c(ID)) %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate (dup_ID = n()) %>%
      ungroup()
    # total household counts, # number of household with family members between 3 and 5 # number of household with count of family members not between 3 and 5
        table_year <- df %>%
          group_by( years) %>%
          summarise(
                Total_HH = n_distinct(ID), # number of householdes
            HH_with_members_3_5 = sum(ifelse(dup_ID %in% 3:5), 1, 0), #
            HH_with_members_less_than_3_and_more_than_5 = sum(ifelse(!(dup_ID %in% 3:5), 1, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df |>
  summarize(households = n_distinct(ID))

df |>
  count(ID) |>
  count(size = if_else(n >= 3 & n <= 5, "3-5", "<3 or >5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with base R as well. One of several ways:

```r
length(unique(df$ID))
#> [1] 17
tab = as.data.frame(table(df$ID)) |> `names<-`(c("ID", "frey"))
tab[tab$frey %in% 3:5, ] |> nrow()
#> [1] 3
tab[! tab$frey %in% 3:5, ] |> nrow()
#> [1] 14
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(2022:2023, times = c(20,25)),
  ID = rep(1:17, times = c(10, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
  Name = paste("name", 1:45), 
  Age = 21:65, 
  Coverage = rep("Yes", 45) 
)
```